# how can i use hibernate to loging in a jsp page

Tags: mysql, hibernate, authentication

im using hibernate with my jsp page and mySQL , i know just how to save a session like that :

```
<%Session hibernateSession = MyDB.HibernateUtil.currentSession();  Transaction tx = hibernateSession.beginTransaction(); 
Student std = new Student(); 
std.setUserName("David");
hibernateSession.save(std);%>
```

, but how can i selecte from a table and print it like in mysql `select * from student wher userName = ***` and how can i update ?

finaly can i use hibernate in Login ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer this for complete HQL help: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html